# Vertical layout of the icon and text in a JMenu

Tags: icons, jmenu

I try to find a way to place the icon of a JMenu above its text. I've seen the method setComponentOrientation(..), but it influences only the horizontal order of the icon and the text (icon on the left side, text on the right - or the opposite). Is there any possibility to place these parts of a JMenu vertically (icon on the top, text under the icon)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are fully able to do that. Maybe this page can help you out. http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/36112-adding-jpanel-jmenu-focus-issues.html I have never really tried adding an image onto a JMenu vertically. You could always try using a JPanel, and adding the JMenu into it, and then setting the layout of the JPanel as a BoxLayout

```
  JLabel imageForIcon = new JLabel(// image path );
  JPanel p = new JPanel(imageForIcon);
  JMenu m = new JMenu(p);
  p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

I am not sure if this would work, but it seems as it could possibly be an option to consider.